# Extending a singleton class

Tags: php, oop, singleton, extend

i used to create an instance of a singleton class like this:

```
$Singleton = SingletonClassName::GetInstance();
```

and for non singleton class:

```
$NonSingleton = new NonSingletonClassName;
```

i think we should not differentiate how we create an instance of a class whether this is a singleton or not. if i look in perception of other class, i don't care whether the class we need a singleton class or not. so, i still not comfortable with how php treat a singleton class. i think and i always want to write:

```
$Singleton = new SingletonClassName;
```

just another non singleton class, is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Tthis isn't a question -- it's you complaining that you don't like how a pattern is done. -1

Comment: This is a very justified question. +1 because -1 isn't :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it as it would make your code a lot harder to understand (People think new means an entirely new object). But then I wouldn't recoemmed the use of Singletons.

The basic idea of this code is that there is a wrapper around a singleton. All functions and variables accessed through that wrapper actually effect the singleton. It isn't perfect as the code below doesn't implement a lot of magic methods and SPL interfaces but they can be added in if required

**Code**

```
/**
 * Superclass for a wrapper around a singleton implementation
 *
 * This class provides all the required functionality and avoids having to copy and
 * paste code for multiple singletons.
 */
class SingletonWrapper{
    private $_instance;
    /**
     * Ensures only derived classes can be constructed
     *
     * @param string $c The name of the singleton implementation class
     */
    protected function __construct($c){
        $this->_instance = &call_user_func(array($c, 'getInstance'));
    }
    public function __call($name, $args){
        call_user_func_array(array($this->_instance, $name), $args);
    }
    public function __get($name){
        return $this->_instance->{$name};
    }
    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->_instance->{$name} = $value;
    }
}

/**
 * A test singleton implementation. This shouldn't be constructed and getInstance shouldn't
 * be used except by the MySingleton wrapper class.
 */
class MySingletonImpl{
    private static $instance = null;
    public function &getInstance(){
        if ( self::$instance === null ){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    //test functions
    public $foo = 1;
    public function bar(){
        static $var = 1;
        echo $var++;
    }
}

/**
 * A wrapper around the MySingletonImpl class
 */
class MySingleton extends SingletonWrapper{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct('MySingletonImpl');
    }
}
```

**Examples**

```
$s1 = new MySingleton();
echo $s1->foo; //1
$s1->foo = 2;

$s2 = new MySingleton();
echo $s2->foo; //2

$s1->bar(); //1
$s2->bar(); //2
```

Answer (score 3):

It better be the other way around - provide a [factory-method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for non-singletons, and get instances of them using:

```
$NonSingleton = NonSingletonClassName::createInstance();
```

This is a recommended best practice for Java (in [Effective Java](http://www.sun.com/books/documents/effective_java_ch02.pdf)), but it applies to most object-oriented languages.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a Singleton the same way as a regular class instance. `new` will always return a new instance, thus you have to have the constructor non-public and thus you have to have a different means to call it from within the class.

You could have factory methods on all classes, e.g. always do `getInstance()` like shown in another answer. Another option would be to use a [Service Locator](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/ServiceLocator.html) and [Dependency Injection Framework](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/) that knows whether to return what.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what `new` keyword means all you want is irrelevant. `new` creates new instance of class, thats why it named **new** :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post, but i understood Factory pattern better with the help of the below link.

So if it helps an future wandered. . . . here goes

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Design-Patterns-in-PHP-Factory-Method-and-Abstract-Factory/1/

It was very simple to grasp and understand the basic implementation.